# Whenever i make one call as non-null asserted, android studio removes warning from the other same variables

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable

Whenever i am trying to create several boolean variables inside a function, which has e: Entry? in it`s constructor, android studio notifies me that only safe or non-null asserted calls are allowed. So, whenever i make one call as non-null asserted, android studio removes this warning from other variables and code is working. Why so?

```
                        val isHighResult = e!!.y >= 3.5
                        val isMediumResult = e.y > 1.5 && e.y < 3.5
                        val isLowResult = e.y <= 1.5
```

Comment: i assume the variable e didn't change since you used the null assertion so if it worked in the  first call it should work for the calls after it if you moved one line to top of the null assertion it'll give you a warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters are constant. Your first line of code guarantees that `e` is either non-null, or that further lines of code will not be reached because it will throw KotlinNullPointerException if `e` is null. So logically, it is not possible for `e` to be null if the second line of code is reached, and the compiler can smart-cast it to a non-nullable Entry.

This is *not* one of the rare cases where it might be OK to use `!!`. There's no reason the code inside this function should expect `e` to be non-null if you declared it as a nullable function parameter. By declaring it nullable, your function is announcing (to programmers that use it) that it's safe to pass null as a parameter.

Comment: I use these variables inside if statement, which checks is e nullable or not. Code is kinda complecated, thus i can`t proceed with ?: . Ty for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: Inside an `if (e != null)` statement, `e` will be smart-cast non-nullable so you won't need `!!`. Also, if you return from the function inside an `if (e != null)` statement, then `e` will be smart-cast non-nullable after the if statement.

Comment: it is a bit more complecated. I use them inside `if (e?.x == x.toFloat())`, which, in turn, is inside `for (x in 0..9)`

Comment: Ah, I see. Then it would be safe to use `!!` inside that if-statement. The condition is just too complicated for the compiler to be able to use it to smart-cast. That is a weird conditional, though. Basically, if `e` or `x` is null, it will throw an exception. I can't see all your code, but it still doesn't look safe.

Comment: Oh wait, I mis read it. Looks like `x` is not the same thing as `e.x`. But if `x` is a String, `toFloat()` crashes if it cannot be parsed into a Float.

Comment: nah, x is from for loop, you were right :)